# Flutter with provider package UI doesn't Update at the detailpage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I wrote a Flutter-app and managed my data with the providers package. With an icon button you can mark a product as a favorite. With my product-item which is loaded into a gridview the UI updates if I favorite a product(the icon changes from a border to a filled icon). But on the detail page which shows more details of a product the UI doesn't update if I press the button.

This is the product class:

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the products class where I manage my data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
}
```

This is the product-item:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String id;
  // final String title;
  // final String imageUrl;

  // ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, child) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  ),
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    product.toggleFavoriteStatus();
                  },
                ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the detail-page:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String title;
  // final double price;

  // ProductDetailScreen(this.title, this.price);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String; // is the id!
    final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).findById(productId);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onTap: () {
              loadedProduct.toggleFavoriteStatus();
            },
            child: Icon(
              loadedProduct.isFavorite ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks to everybody who tries to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't update the UI because there is no Provider or Consumer of type `Product` to listen to those changes in the new route. You have `Provider<Products>` and extract a `Product` from there, but that's it, the route doesn't depend on/listen that `Product` because there is no `Provider<Product>` in that part of the widget tree

I would recommend to expose the value of the provider to the new route instead of passing the id and creating a new Provider.

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
    ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
    arguments: product, //pass the Product instead of the id
  );
},

class ProductDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String title;
  // final double price;

  // ProductDetailScreen(this.title, this.price);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvier<Product>.value(
       value: ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Product
       child: Consumer<Product>(
         builder: (context, loadedProduct, _){
           return Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
               title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
               actions: <Widget>[
                 IconButton(
                   onTap: () {
                     loadedProduct.toggleFavoriteStatus();
                   },
                   child: Icon(
                     loadedProduct.isFavorite ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                     color: Colors.white,
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           );
         }
       )
    );
  }
}
```